# Trying to access profiles of instagram accounts through urls

Tags: python

I have a series of instagram account url profiles I am trying to scrap (number of followers, number of people following etc). I have these urls of the profiles I am interested in. When I enter these into the browser, I can access them no problem, but through requests in python, I keep getting 'Not found'. I was wondering if someone could take a look.

```
    import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

data = pd.read_csv('HashTagCSV')
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data)

posturl = dataframe.iloc[:, 0]
username = dataframe.iloc[:, 2]
commentcount = dataframe.iloc[:, 4]
likecount = dataframe.iloc[:, 5]

final_data_frame = dataframe.iloc[:, [1, 4, 5]]
final_data_frame.dropna(inplace=True)
print(final_data_frame)

final_data_frame['commentCount'] = pd.to_numeric(final_data_frame['commentCount'], errors='coerce')
final_data_frame['likeCount'] = pd.to_numeric(final_data_frame['likeCount'], errors='coerce')
final_data_frame['commentCount'] = final_data_frame['commentCount'].replace(np.nan, 0)
final_data_frame['likeCount'] = final_data_frame['likeCount'].replace(np.nan, 0)

dictionary_list = []

for row in final_data_frame.itertuples():
    
        if int(row.commentCount) > 50 and int(row.likeCount) > 200:
            
            dictionary = {'url': row.profileUrl, 'comments': row.commentCount, 'likes': row.likeCount}
            
            dictionary_list.append(dictionary)
            
new_data_frame = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictionary_list)
#print(new_data_frame)  
new_data_frame = new_data_frame.iloc[:, 0]
#print(new_data_frame)
data_frame = pd.DataFrame(new_data_frame)
print(data_frame)     
profileurl_list = data_frame['url'].values.tolist()
print(profileurl_list)     

#for url in profileurl_list:
    #url = 'https://www.instagram.com/'+username
 
    
#for names in profileurl_list:  

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/jojajovana11')


#pop_up_box = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mount_0_0_Hp"]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div')

try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mount_0_0_OO"]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/button[2]'))).click()
except:
    driver.close()
    
#cookie_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="mount_0_0_OO"]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/button[2]')
#cookie_button.click()
```

Comment: Is this compliant with IGs ToS?

Comment: I am not sure. But when I use the link in my browser, I can easily go to their profile page. The problem I am having now is that I cant get selenium to click accept cookies box.

Comment: Any ideas? Finding some responses online but cant pinpoint any specifics